# Jumping to sections of the page using only Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've just started to code, and am learning all there is to know about JQuery. I have a navbar with 'About' and 'What is this' anchors. The specific content for the respective anchors are in different sections of the page. If I click an anchor, say 'About', I want to jump to the 'About-content' section of the webpage. I have read of plugins which do this, but is there any way to do this simply using JQuery? I tried doing what was told in an answer to a similar question but it doesn't work.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="About"> <a href="#"> About </a></li>
  <li class="How-it-works"> <a href="#"> How it works </a></li>

</ul>
......
......

<div class="About-content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p> text text text </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.About').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('body, html').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".About-content").offset.top
        }, 600);

    })
}
```

Comment: Define "*it doesn't work*," how does it not work? What goes wrong? Are there any error messages in your browser console?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/ZVdRt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change your target `.About-content` to an `#About-content`
- Change the `href` to `#About-content`
- Remove `e.preventDefault()`

It should function without jQ/JS but if you add easing to your animation then it'd be useful.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.About').click(function(event) {
    $('body, html').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#About-content").offset().top
    }, 600);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="About"> <a href="#About-content"> About </a>
  </li>
  <li class="How-it-works"> <a href="#"> How it works </a>
  </li>

</ul>
<div style="height: 1000px;"></div>
<div id="About-content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p>text text text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why you are suggesting an id, a class should work fine

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you, I'm very grateful for this! I have follow-up questions for my own education-
1. Why do we need to change the class to ID to get it to work? Is it always the case with scrolling using JQuery?

2.Can the href in the anchor be ".About-content" to target a class?

3. The top nav bar is fixed, so when the animation happens, a part of the About content gets hidden by the nav bar. Is there a way to scroll it a little bit more towards the bottom, relative to its new position?

Comment: @KeshavVasudevan Great! Don't forget to click the green checkmark. 1. No you can use a class, jQuery will work with it, I changed to id because it's a solid fallback when there's no JS for some reason. 2. See no. 1. 3.Sure you can use the `offset()` property like if you wanted to subtract 100px then do this: `scrollTop: $("#About-content").offset().top -100}, 600);`

Answer (score 2):

Use the id attribute to your target div:

```
<div id="About-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p>text text text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Set Nav link to the Div id:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="About"> <a href="#About-content"> About </a>
    </li>
    <li class="How-it-works"> <a href="#"> How it works </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Use the following simple jquery for smooth scroll:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".About a").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#About-content").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you so much for this!  The person below has also given the same answer, and I had a few follow-up questions for my own education-
1. Why do we need to change the class to ID to get it to work? Is it always the case with scrolling using JQuery?

2.Can the href in the anchor be ".About-content" to target a class?

3. The top nav bar is fixed, so when the animation happens, a part of the About content gets hidden by the nav bar. Is there a way to scroll it a little bit more towards the bottom, relative to its new position?

Comment: Requirements:
1. <a> elements must have an href attribute that begin with # and be more than just #. An element on the page with a matching id attribute                            2.The href in the anchor cannot be ".About-content" to target a class. It must have an id to target the div.                                                              3.You can use margin-bottom of the nav bar to show the About content properly.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an `Nav` like this ,

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="About"> <a href="#About-content"> About </a></li>
                    <li class="How-it-works"> <a href="#HowItWorks"> How it works </a> </li>   
</ul>
```

And assuming a `div` like what you have,

Some Content Here

```
  $(document).ready(function(){     
      $(".navbar-nav a").on('click', function(event) {  
      event.preventDefault(); 
      var hash = this.hash;  
      $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1000, function(){
         window.location.hash = hash;
        });
      });
    })
```

Will animate to the respective areas. Here `hash` holds the values after `#` from your `<a>`tags.

IMHO, its better to bind the click event on the `.nav` instead of binding with separate `<a>`'s.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a very nice way of going at this, I never knew we could approach this problem in this way. What does the window.location do?

Comment: @KeshavVasudevan It just shows the div in our case returning the object `hash` in our case. [Read More..](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know about jquery. but you can do it more simply by bootstrap. Like this. It is called bootstrap scrollspy. If you like the answer please rate it. :)

```css
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
  body {
      position: relative; 
  }
  #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section41 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section42 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
```

```html
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

    
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>

           
     
    
  
    

<div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
 
</div>
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>

</div>
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
 
</div>
```